# Unnest with sampled values in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have an f_id and e_id to unnest. when unnesting e_id, can i limit to 100 rows only?

```
with first_brkdwn AS (
            SELECT
                t.f_id,
                t.e
            FROM raw1
            CROSS JOIN UNNEST(s) AS t(f_id, e)
        ),

        req AS (
            SELECT
                a.*
            FROM first_brkdwn a
            JOIN sel b
                ON CAST(a.f_id AS INT) = CAST(b.f_id AS INT)
                
        ),

        final as
        (
        SELECT
            f_id,
            e_id
        FROM req f
        CROSS JOIN UNNEST(e) AS t(e_id)
        )
        select * from final
```

for the line `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(e) AS t(e_id)` can I unnest limited to just 100 values.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `WITH ORDINALITY` clause. For example consider the following:

```sql
SELECT numbers, n, a
FROM (
  VALUES
    (ARRAY[2, 5]),
    (ARRAY[7, 8, 9, 4])
) AS x (numbers)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (n, a)
where a < 4;
```

Which results in:

| numbers | n | a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [2, 5] | 2 | 1 |
| [2, 5] | 5 | 2 |
| [7, 8, 9, 4] | 7 | 1 |
| [7, 8, 9, 4] | 8 | 2 |
| [7, 8, 9, 4] | 9 | 3 |

i.e. the the "excess" rows were filtered out.

So your `final` can look something like:

```sql
final as (
    SELECT
        f_id,
        e_id
    FROM req f
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(e) WITH ORDINALITY AS t(e_id, rn)
    WHERE rn <= 100)
```